# Flickering in CSS3 animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

There is a flickering of the animation from the destination point to the initial point before the animation actually starts. If you run it for a second time, it's noticeable.

I have to use it several times on the same page. Therefore I need it to not flicker.

http://jsfiddle.net/wb0m9L3h/

```
@-webkit-keyframes sjl {
from {
    background-position: 0px -5000px;
}
to {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
}
@-moz-keyframes sjl {
from {
    background-position: 0px -5000px;
}
to {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
}
@-ms-keyframes sjl {
from {
    background-position: 0px -5000px;
}
to {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
}
@-o-keyframes sjl {
from {
    background-position: 0px -5000px;
}
to {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
}
@keyframes sjl {
from {
    background-position: 0px -5000px;
}
to {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
}
.sjl
/*Squirrel jump left*/
 {
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
-webkit-perspective: 1000; //tried to use this and the 3 lines below but in every combination, even placing it in body but doesn't solve the problem
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-animation: sjl 1.5s steps(20) alternate;
-moz-animation: sjl 1.5s steps(20) alternate;
-ms-animation: sjl 1.5s steps(20) alternate;
-o-animation: sjl 1.5s steps(20) alternate;
animation: sjl 1.5s steps(20) alternate;
background-image:url(http://s9.postimg.org/io6wluqhb/Sjl.png) !important;
position: absolute;
float: left;
top: 120px;
left: 10px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Although CSS animation flickering can be a regular issue, one way to try and mitigate it is to instantiate Hardware Acceleration on the element with `translate3d(0, 0, 0)` http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d

Comment: I tried using translate3d(0, 0, 0) , animation doesn't play at all. after clicking on the button only the end position of the animation is visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps property in the **animation-timing-function** is a little bit misleading.

If you have 20 images, then the number if steps is not 20, it's 19. It's clearer for a smaller number. If you have only 2 states, the number of steps is only 1.

As a consequence of this, you are repeating at the end of the animation the first frame.

You need also to adjust the keyframes **background-position** property, the last value shouldn't be the total size of the image, but the displacement to get there. Another way of calculating this is that it is 19/20 of your current value.

**[here](https://jsfiddle.net/wb0m9L3h/12/)** you can see the 2 animations, side by side. Notice how, in the left one (the original one), there is awrong frame, that is not appearing in the right side one.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes sjl {
    from {     background-position: 0px -5000px;    }
    to {        background-position: 0px 0px;    }
}
@keyframes sjl {
    from {   background-position: 0px -5000px;    }
    to {        background-position: 0px 0px;    }
}
.sjl
 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    -webkit-animation: sjl 2s steps(20) alternate infinite;
    animation: sjl 2s steps(20) alternate;
    background-image:url(http://s9.postimg.org/io6wluqhb/Sjl.png) !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sjlok {
    from {     background-position: 0px -4750px;    }
    to {        background-position: 0px 0px;    }
}
@keyframes sjlok {
    from {   background-position: 0px -4750px;    }
    to {        background-position: 0px 0px;    }
}

#ok {
    left: 300px;
    -webkit-animation: sjlok 2s steps(19) alternate infinite;
    animation: sjlok 2s steps(19) alternate;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div  class="sjl"></div>
    <div  class="sjl" id="ok"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for not only giving the answer but explaining it too. thanks again